# Converting a trie into a reverse trie?

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, trie

Suppose that I have a **[trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)** data structure holding a number of strings.  To look up a string in the trie, I would start at the root and follow the pointer labeled with the appropriate characters of the string, in order, until I arrived at a given node.

Now suppose that I want to build a "reverse trie" for the same set of strings, where instead of looking up strings by starting with the *first* character, I would look up strings by starting with the *last* character.

Is there an efficient algorithm for turning tries into reverse tries?  In the worst case I could always list off all the strings in the trie and then insert them one-at-a-time into a reverse trie, but it seems like there might be a better, more clever solution.

Comment: The reverse trie will have no obvious relation to the original trie, so there is probably no better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But the nodes in your trie are in essentially random order, if your ordering criteria is based on the strings' reverse. That is, given the sequence `[aardvark, bat, cat, dog, elephant, fox]`, which are in alphabetical order, reversing the words would not give you the sequence `[xof, tnahpele, god, tac, tab, kravdraa]`.

In other words, there's no "more clever solution" than to build your reverse trie.